# Jupyter add markdown heading within loop

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm creating plots in a loop in Jupyter notebook. Is it possible to auto generate markdown heading within a loop before every figure so that the headings can show up in jupyter toc or vscode outline for easy navigation?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for i in range(1,5):
    #add markdown heading here

    plt.figure()
    x = np.arange(10)*i
    y = np.sin(x)
    plt.plot(x, y)
```

Comment: You could make the output display as markdown using something like the approach [described for printmd here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterlab-dictionary-content-output-format/5863/2?u=fomightez) here. However, I don't think table of contents would see that. I think you'd have to write some fancy extension to automate something like what you describe in real time. Like if it sees you make a plot, it prompts you to provide text to place in markdown and does it. However, ...

Comment: You could make a variable while writing your plot code that is something like `mdtext_to_add_above = '## Plot title here'`, & then make a script that you call with the path and notebook file name as a argument and have the script insert a markdown cell with that content as the string in `mdtext_to_add_above`above that cell using [nbformat](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/delete-all-code-cells-except-markdown-text/3072/2?u=fomightez) **after-the-fact** There may be a way to do that with a preprocessor or postprocessor in nbconvert too, but it would involve running nbconvert after the fact, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the cell type of any cell in Jupyter Notebook using the Toolbar. The default cell type is Code. To use the Keyboard Shortcuts, hit the esc key. After that, you can change a cell to Markdown by hitting the m key, or you can change a cell to Code by hitting the y key

[see this image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgfrJ.png)

Comment: slightly edited question to emphasize the goal is to auto generate markdown heading within the loop.